# Logging into form with cURL/PHP

Tags: php, symfony-2.1, php-curl

I'm trying to login to an external site with PHP's curl protocol.

This is the form in question

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/support/login" method="post">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
    <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="pHEFLN4N1cLB/L8hnL1BBD6MK6tZ1s5VFceXlLaM48o="/>
    <input class="required special" id="user_session_email" name="user_session[email]" type="email" value="" />
    <input class="special" id="user_session_password" name="user_session[password]" type="password">
    <input name="user_session[remember_me]" type="hidden" value="0" />
    <input checked="checked" id="user_session_remember_me" name="user_session[remember_me]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-login"> Login</button>
</form>
```

And this is what I have so far:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$url = "example_url";
$username = "example@example.com";
$password = "example_password";
$postInfo = http_build_query(array('user_session[email]' => $username, 'user_session[password]' => $password));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postInfo);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

I know that I need to build in handling for the authenticity token, as well as user session storage (cookie jar?) and possibly the "remember me" button too. But, right now I'm getting an error from the return html that no verification information was registered at all, so clearly nothing I have is working.

Comment: It's probably because you left out the `authenticity_token` parameter.

Comment: You'll need to implement cookies to be able to continue after logging in, but the authenticity token is needed just to send the login form in the first place.

Comment: What would be a valid way to retrieve the auth token and post form data in the same curl session, or is that possible?

Comment: The auth token presumably comes from the page that creates the form in the first place. So you need to `GET` that page, parse it to find the auth token, and then include its value when you submit the login info.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to call `http_build_query()`. If you use an array in `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, it will be formatted properly by `curl`.

Comment: I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to do all of this in one curl session 

1. Hit endpoint with GET request like you suggested 
2. Get redirected to login page 
3. Grab authenticity token from login page, fill out form, submit form 
4. Follow redirect
5. Do whatever while logged in. 

I'm assuming I need to use cookie jar to share the session information after following the redirect, possibly between multiple curl sessions. is that accurate?

Comment: Yes, that sounds about right. There are other questions on SO about how to use `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` to maintain session cookies when logging in.